# Geb: Getting value from dropdown datalist (Element not visible error)

Tags: geb, html-datalist

I need to select an option from a datalist which gets populated after a short time duration. This is what I have tried-unsuccessfully- so far.

Module module.groovy

```
inputBox { $("input", 0) }
clientListItemOne{ $("datalist option", 0) }
clientListItemTwo { $("datalist option", 3) }
clientListItemThree { $("datalist option", 7) }
```

UI Test

```
 try{
     module.inputBox.click().click()
     waitFor("quick") { module.clientListItemOne.displayed }
     module.clientListItemOne.click()
 }
```

The result is that even though the dropdown datalist is visible, the browser gets stuck in the waitFor loop and quits.

Without using the waitFor loop, I get an 'element not visible' error.

How do I remedy this situation?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: First off, why are you double clicking the inputBox? I'm assuming that's a typo. Secondly, I've had a lot of trouble in the past using Geb/Selenium to handle new html5 elements, particularly with input validation. It may not be supported. Try checking if $("datalist") is present in your waitFor{}  Is the element getting picked up in the DOM? Can you see it in your web inspector?

Comment: The datalist is a dropdown and I have to click the input box twice to get it to appear. datalist appears as greyed out in the DOM. In the end, I manually passed in the values for input.

Comment: Also, datalist is not supported in safari. 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: No this was in Firefox :)